# Can we create a child with name child.parent using DNN community edition?

Tags: mobile, dotnetnuke

I am using **DNN Community edition** for my website.In that am trying to create a separate mobile version.

So can we create `m.domainname.com` for mobile version of the website using **DNN community edition**.

My main site is - `www.domainname.com`

I like to create - `www.m.domainname.com`

Is is possible in **DNN community edition**.Please help me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible in DNN, you simply need to add a new "portal/site" in the Host/Sites page. You can add a new "Parent" no need to call it a "Child" in DNN. A parent allows you to configure different Subdomains.

Comment: Hi @Chris Hammond.Thanks for you response. I have tried all the ways. I have tried to create parent also. But it was not allowing me to create a site with the name m.DomainName. Even I have tried site aliases with m.domainname, but the DNS was not identifying the site name and it was not at all loading with the site alias. 
Note:We are trying to create the same in our local.The url for the parent site is IP:Port.